# Docker Nginx connect to PHP-FPM on private docker network

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am trying to connect my docker nginx container to my docker php7 container. I have both connected to a private bridge network, because I want my php engine offline. When starting my nginx container I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php7" in 
 etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:11
```

My php container command (run first):

```
docker run -d \
    --name php7 \
    -v /php7:/usr/local/etc \
    -v /www_data:/www \
    --network=priv-bridge-net \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    php:7.0.24-fpm
```

My nginx command:

```
docker run -d \
    --name nginx \
    -v /nginx_conf:/etc/nginx \
    -v /www_data:/usr/share/nginx/html \
    --network=priv-bridge-net \
    nginx:1.13.5
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name test;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php7:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!
Second question, can I eliminate the  -p 9000:9000 from the php container, because it is on the same bridge network on as the nginx server.

Comment: Also, I tried putting the networkname.containername in the php location info in the nginx.conf  `fastcgi_pass priv-bridge-net.php7:9000`

Comment: Perhaps helpful to continue troubleshooting - I replicated what you're doing except for mounting volumes in my php container, nginx works fine. User defined network, copy/paste nginx.conf. I can also confirm in my nginx container that `php7` is recognized as a hostname.

Comment: Ok, I will play around with it a bit more, maybe experiment with no mounts at first. 
Firewall shouldn't matter right? port 9000 is not open on the firewall to my server, but the connection shouldn't be going out of the docker environment/server, right?

Comment: yeah if you're running everything locally, firewall doesn't care. FYI I did not specify `-p 9000:9000' for my php server. That's down the road, right now you aren't even seeing the php7 container from your nginx container.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it worked out! Some problem w/ order of start and conflict with other containers. Yes, I'm going to remove the exposing the port, since I don't want it internet-facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so my above question IS the correct answer. I was just having trouble with the order of starting containers (I also have reverse proxies and others in play, it got a bit confusing).

For anyone who wants to connect docker nginx to a docker php, this is correct setup:

My php container command (run first):

```
docker run -d \
    --name php7 \
    -v /php7:/usr/local/etc \
    -v /www_data:/www \
    --network=priv-bridge-net \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    php:7.0.24-fpm
```

My nginx command:

```
docker run -d \
    --name nginx \
    -v /nginx_conf:/etc/nginx \
    -v /www_data:/usr/share/nginx/html \
    --network=priv-bridge-net \
    nginx:1.13.5
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name test;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php7:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```